# Построение графов по AS

Tags: isp, маршрутизация

Всем привет! На каких данных основываются, чтобы построить графы по автономным системам? Однозначно они не берут из [www.ripe.net](https://apps.db.ripe.net/search/query.html?searchtext=AS31133&search%3AdoSearch=Search#resultsAnchor).

[image]

Comment: Я бы посоветовал бы вам переформулировать свой вопрос. Потому как лично я не понимаю вас. Что вы хотите узнать?

Comment: Эээ, глазки поднимите выше, там же синим по английскому написано - BGP.

Comment: А что не понятно-то, построить графы по AS это из раздела динамической маршрутизации (BGP), откуда они данные берут для построения....

Comment: @ХэшКод, зря вы так. Оригинальная диаграмма была интерактивна, а картинка - просто картинка. Собственно, помимо красивой диаграммы, это looking glass - тулза для отладки BGP, только в Hurricane Electric реализовали её с душой. По-моему, заслуживает ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

Как Вам уже сказали, берут из данных BGP.

Чтобы получить руками — нужно лезть в BGP-демона (Quagga, Bird и иже с ними), заставляя его разобрать пути из приходящих анонсов на орграф.

Но показать суть можно и без того. Возьму для примера адрес Hashcode:

```
border# show ip bgp 94.127.69.51
BGP routing table entry for 94.127.64.0/21
Paths: (2 available, best #2, table Default-IP-Routing-Table)
  Not advertised to any peer
  20764 35000 48235
    [... информация по маршруту RASCOM ...]

  9002 35000 48235
    [... информация по маршруту от RETN ...]
```

Вот мы и видим, что AS20764 пирится с AS35000, а те, в свою очередь, с AS48235. Вот он, маленький кусочек, этих данных. Если разобрать пути всех маршрутов, то можно получить граф, таким, как мы его видим с одной AS. Если одна хорошо географически размазанная AS (или, лучше, несколько их) такое сделают — данные будут точнее и интереснее.

Answer (score 0):

В bgp это называется атрибутом path, чем короче путь тем лучше маршрут. Дело не в этом, а задумайтесь почему он берет только AS выборочные и наносит их на graph, не те с которыми вы neighbors. Может Hurricane Electric как-то анализирует куда больше идет трафик... Если посмотреть сколько пиров к ТТК или МЕГАФОНА, то на графе одни точки будут.

Comment: Предположение — видимо, есть функция веса ноды (AS). Например, по размеру IP-пространства, или по числу соседей, или по еще чему-либо. Если нод слишком много — берется сколько-то с максимальными весами, а мелкие ноды на графе не отображаются как малозначительные. Но это только предположение, никак не подтвержденное фактами. Можно посмотреть на графы крупных AS, посчитать — если там будет фиксированный максимум нод (скажем, всегда до 30), то, видимо, как-то так. Мне лень, увы :)